# How do I add time zone hours to a date in SparkR?

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a Spark (1.6.3) Dataframe columns date "created_at" and offset "utc_offset":

```
dt<-df$created_at
head(df)
                      created_at utc_offset
1 Sun Jul 31 22:25:01 +0000 2016       <NA>
2 Sun Jul 31 22:25:01 +0000 2016       <NA>
3 Fri Jun 03 10:16:57 +0000 2016     -25200
4 Mon May 30 19:23:55 +0000 2016     -18000
```

I want to add the offset to the date. I try:

```
str <- strptime(dt, "%a %b %d   %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT")
dt.gmt <- as.POSIXct(str, tz = "GMT")
dt.gmt<-ifelse (is.na(df$utc_offset),dt.gmt, dt.gmt+df$utc_offset)
class(dt.gmt) <- c("POSIXct")
head(dt.gmt)
```

which gives:

```
> dt.gmt<-ifelse (is.na(df$utc_offset),dt.gmt, dt.gmt+df$utc_offset)
Error in unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(df$utc_offset) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'
> class(dt.gmt) <- c("POSIXct")
> head(dt.gmt)
[1] NA                        "2016-02-02 09:38:12 GMT" "2016-02-02 09:38:45 GMT" "2016-02-02 09:39:31 GMT" "2016-02-02 09:40:14 GMT" "2016-02-02 09:41:12 GMT"
```

I thought is.na would cover me. I suppose it could be dt.gmt that is not numeric. Is there any easy way to print out the non-numerics for each column? 
But I do get output although it does not correspond in any way to the input (I think my earliest date is May 2016).

Comment: For datetime, it is better not to use `ifelse`

Comment: Thanks. What is the alternative?